# Удаление дубликатов строк из файла сохраняя порядок строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый файл:

```
автозапчасти лексус новосибирск
автозапчасти лексус в туле
запчасти для lexus ls 460
разборка lexus rx
запчасти на лексус rx 330 бу
разборка lexus rx
```

Можно ли при помощи Python 3 удалить дубликаты строк?

Comment: Думал что на такое распространенное действие есть уже готовое решение. Похоже заблуждался...

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order

Answer (score 2):

Возможно. К примеру так:

```
def delete_string():
    File = open('test.txt', 'r')
    str_list = []
    for i in File.readlines():
        if i not in str_list:
            str_list.append(i)
    File.close()
    File = open(a, 'w')
    for j in str_list:
        File.write(j)
```

Код не качественный. Но сойдёт :)

Comment: Не работает. ..Ошибка Syntax Error: def delete_string(): <string>, line 2, pos 20

Comment: Разве не видно ошибку? После названия функции я забыл ":" Исправил

Answer (score 2):

Нашел рабочее решение:

```
file ='C:\\words.txt'

uniqlines = set(open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines())
gotovo = open(file,'w', encoding='utf-8').writelines(set(uniqlines))
```

Оно удаляет дубликаты. Но к сожаление еще и меняет расположение строк.
Так что вопрос остается актуальным.

Comment: Оригинальное решение! Дважды только зачем-то преобразование в множество, да и файлы не закрываются

Comment: не нужды дважды `set()` вызывать. [Можно `OrderedDict` использовать, чтобы порядок сохранить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631520/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Можно [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) воспользоваться, чтобы файл по месту изменить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(inplace=True, backup='.bak', mode='rb') as file:
    seen = set()
    for line in file:
        if line not in seen: # first time
            seen.add(line)
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(line) # redirected to the file
```

Пример:

```
T:\> python remove-duplicates-inplace.py C:\words.txt
```

Строки сравниваются буквально, то есть даже если отличие только в пробелах, строки рассматриваются различными. Можно нормализовать пробелы, если необходимо:

```
for line in file:
    words = tuple(line.split())
    if words not in seen:
       seen.add(words)
       sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
```

Можно руками файлы открывать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = r'C:\words.txt'
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    uniq = OrderedDict.fromkeys(file)
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.writelines(uniq)
```

Оба решения требуют, чтобы уникальные строки можно было бы в память загрузить. Если это не так, то можно воспользоваться [внешней сортировкой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279), чтобы повторяющиеся строки шли бы подряд в файле, а затем удалить их, [используя алгоритм, который не загружает уникальные строки в память.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631525/23044).

Answer (score 1):

[mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) | [os](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os) | [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#module-shutil)

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from os import close
from shutil import move

def write_lines(file='words.txt'):
    ft, temp = mkstemp()  # создать temp-файл
    lines = []  # "уникальные" строки из file
    with open(temp, 'w') as t, open(file) as f:
        for line in f:  # читать file построчно
            if line not in lines:  # для line, отсутствующих в lines
                lines.append(line)  # сохранить line в lines
                t.write(line)  # записать line в temp-файл
    close(ft)  # закрыть temp-файл
    move(temp, file)  # переместить/переименовать temp-файл в file
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, как работает ваш код.

Comment: Есть же комментарии. Всё очевидно)

Comment: Это квадратичный алгоритм (вдвойне не имеет смысла использовать подобное решение: если ввод маленький (и временная сложность не важна), то не имеет смысла временный файл использовать: можно просто строки в память прочитать. Если ввод даже умерено большой, то [квадратичный алгоритм слишком медленный может быть](https://goo.gl/JWFQxv)

Answer (score 1):

Версия в **2021**, для Python **3.7+** со стандартными *(встроенными)* функциями

```python
text = """\
автозапчасти лексус новосибирск
автозапчасти лексус в туле
запчасти для lexus ls 460
разборка lexus rx
запчасти на лексус rx 330 бу
разборка lexus rx\
"""
    
rows = text.splitlines()
    
unique_rows = dict.fromkeys(rows)  # Получаем словарь
    
new_text = "\n".join(unique_rows)  # Соединяем ключи словаря в строку
```

Для следующих гугл юзеров :)

Comment: я так понимаю это просто OrderedDict решение [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631520/23044), без кода для чтения/записи в файл и не нужным `list` вызовом. Оно работает так как в Python 3.7+ гарантированно что dict упорядочен.

Comment: @jfs Да. Всё верно. В моём ответе на это и упор: что не нужно ничего импортировать, включая `OrderedDict`. А вызов list() сделан для очевидности, что мы получаем список на выходе. Но вы правы, .join() прекрасно проглатывает и словарь и сам вызывает list() под капотом. Но, вдруг, кто-то этот список будет не в join() передавать =)

Comment: "обход словаря в Питоне возвращает ключи" -- это следует считать обязательным знанием для программистов Питона (можно комментарий для образования оставить поясняющий (если ответ для совсем начинающих), но не стоит код уродовать лишними вызовами).