# Как оставить только уникальные линии в текстовом файле?

Tags: python

Есть файл из несколько миллионов строк (линий), нужно удалить все дубликаты (если у нас 2 одинаковые строки, оставить только одну из них (порядок не важен))

Пример на массиве:

```
[1,6,2,3,4,5,6,5,6] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А общий размер файла какой? В памяти помещается? Если да, то просто кладёте строки в множество, если строка уже есть в множестве - пропускаете её при записи в новый файл.

Comment: 200mb, 20м строк

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631054/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 2):

Пример на псевдокоде:

- создаёте пустое множество
- открываете файл на чтение
- открываете новый файл на запись
- читаете файл построчно

  - если строка уже есть во множестве, то переход к следующей строке
  - иначе добавляете эту строку во множество и записываете её в новый файл
- закрываете файлы